# What happens when you try to cast an object that is null in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, casting, null

I've got the following code:

```
[application.tripHandler createTrip:picker.date
                          pickUpAddress:[ModelUtil addresFragmentFromGeoAddress:pickUpAddress]
                       orPickUpLocation:pickUpFavorite
                      andDropOffAddress:[ModelUtil addresFragmentFromGeoAddress:dropOffAddress]
                      orDropOffLocation:dropOffFavorite forDriver:application.currentDriver.driverId
                             completion:^(NSObject *entity)
     {
         if(application.dispatchVehicle)
         {
             Trip *createdTrip = (Trip *)entity;
```

What happens when entity is null?

Comment: You can check it yourself but forcing entity as null/nill.. and putting a break point or NSLog there by the way  Trip *createdTrip will be nil if entity is nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `entity` is `nil`, then `createdTrip` will be `nil` as well.

(`nil` and `NULL` are technically the same thing, but `nil` is semantically the null object value whereas `NULL` is the null pointer).

Casting a pointer does not actually do anything at runtime. It merely modifies the type being pointed-to, which then affects subsequent operations on the resulting value. But the actual pointer value will remain the same through the cast.

Answer (score 0):

`createdTrip` will be `nil` object.

Answer (score 0):

In obj-c, a cast doesnt do anything during runtime, so you will just assign nil.